# How to create a linq extension method with Func<>?

Tags: c#, .net

I've created extension methods that can be used like this:

```
string returnValue = numbers.At(separator, index).Slice();
```

But I want to create like this:

```
string returnValue = numbers.At(s => '.').Slice();
```

Here's the other code.

```
 public class StringParameters
 {
     public string Text { get; set; }
     public int Position { get; set; }

     public StringParameters(string text, int position)
     {
         this.Text = text;
         this.Position = position;
     }
 }

 public static StringParameters At(this string text, char c)
 {
     int index = text.IndexOf(c);
     if (index > 0)
     {
         int index2 = text.IndexOf(c, index + 1);
         if (index2 > index)
         {
             text = text.Substring(index2, text.Length - index2);
         }

         return new StringParameters(text, index2 + 1);
     }

     return new StringParameters(null, -1);
 }

 public static string Slice(this StringParameters parameters)
 {
     return parameters.Text.Substring(parameters.Position);
 }
```

**Edit:** I've edited the code and replaced ... with "something here". I do not still get the full idea what it should be there. My expectation is that the method should be more useful by this.

**Edit 2:** I have now an idea what I want to create with my code. I want to be able to make something like this:

```
string returnValue = numbers.At(s, i => GetStringParameter()).Slice();
```

**Edit 3:** I've edited the code a little bit. It will probably be more clearer now of what I want to achieve.

**Edit 4:** Corrected a mistake in the code above.

Comment: What would the `Func<>` do exactly?

Comment: The `i => ...` isn't valid code - what should this look like? And what is the type of the `Func<>` you want to use? is it `Func<T>`, `Func<R, T>`, `Func<R1, R2, T>`, etc?

Comment: Also, why have you created an intermediate `StringParameters` class. Why not just do `static string Slice(this string text, char c, int start)`?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you explect i to be.. based on the name, it would seem you would think it's an index, but there isn't any way for your method to know what index you want, I also don't know what you want to return from this func, a bool?  an index?  What are you trying to achieve with this delegate?

Comment: Please see the update. Ask if there's something other on your mind. I'm interested in any code snippets that could help me proceed on this.

Comment: I assume you've checked existing methods (i.e. in `Enumerable` class) -  clarifying where you have problem to apply such knowledge would help.

Comment: I've checked this link https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq but I could not understand how they create linq methods. It is too hardcore for me. :)

Comment: @DeividasGrigas - Can you explain what you are trying to achieve here? (Ignore the `Func<>` for now - what's your goal?)

Comment: I want code like this: string returnValue = numbers.At(s, i => GetStringParameter).Slice(); where i'll be able to get parameters from another method or manipulate them like you can manipulate in a Where clause. I hope this is more understandable.

Comment: I've updated the code a little bit. Please see it again. It is a bit more clearer now of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear for me what are you trying to achieve (`start` parameter, which you want to replace by function, is not used anywhere in `At` function), but here is an example extension function with Func<> parameter:

```
public static StringParameters At(this string text, char c, Func<int> startFunc)
{
    int start = startFunc();
    int index = text.IndexOf(c);
    if (index > 0)
    {
        int index2 = text.IndexOf(c, index + 1);
        if (index2 > index)
        {
            text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - index2);
        }

        return new StringParameters(text, index2 + 1);
    }

    return new StringParameters(null, -1);
}
```

Usage:

```
string returnValue = numbers.At(s, () => GetStartIndex()).Slice();
```

You don't need `i =>` here until you have an argument that you will pass to the `Func<>` inside `At` function.

When you call `int start = startFunc();`, the function you passed as the parameter to `At` (`GetStartIndex()` in my example) will be called and its return value will be set to `start` variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
string returnValue = numbers.At(s, i => GetStringParameter()).Slice();
```

with the `Slice` extension method having a signature:

```
 public static string Slice(this StringParameters parameters)
```

i.e. you want

```
 StringParameters stringParameters = numbers.At(s, i => GetStringParameter());
 string returnValue = stringParameters.Slice();
```

It sounds like you need an overload of your extension method, `At`, to have a signature like:

```
public static StringParameters At(this string text, S s, Func<T, U> func)
```

Where `S` is the type of the `s` you're passing in, `T` is the input to your [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and `U` is the output type of the Func.

In the `At` method, you use your Func like you'd call a method, e.g.

```
Func<int, string> func = (int)i => i.ToString();
string s = func(123); // s == "123"
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't understand how to use Func in the At() method.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the solution with the help of Aleksey Shubin and others. The final code looks like this:

```
public static class Linq
{
    public class StringParameters
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }

        public StringParameters(string text, int position)
        {
            this.Text = text;
            this.Position = position;
        }
    }

    public static StringParameters At(this string text, Func<char> func)
    {
        char c = func();
        int index = text.IndexOf(c);
        if (index > 0)
        {
            int index2 = text.IndexOf(c, index + 1);
            if (index2 > index)
            {
                text = text.Substring(index2, text.Length - index2);
            }

            return new StringParameters(text, index2 + 1);
        }

        return new StringParameters(null, -1);
    }

   public static string Cut(this StringParameters parameters)
   {
       return parameters.Text.Substring(parameters.Position);
   }
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
string returnValue = "132.465..646.656.45".At(() => '.').Cut();
```

This returns the value of 6.45. It should return the value of 656.45 or probably 132.465, but this is pretty easy. Thanks everyone for your help.